# Jetpack compose navigation popUpTo inclusive true not cleared composable screen from backstack

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, jetpack-compose-navigation

I am using Jetpack Compose ui version `1.3.0-beta08` and navigation compose version `2.4.0-alpha02` and working Bloom app with all new Architecture components. After login success I need to clear all previous compose login screens, but even added `popUpTo("HomeScreen"){inclusive = true}`, my login screen removed from backstack, but login welcome screen not removed from backstack, when I click back from Home screen. is it anything I am missing/wrong in compose navigation?

```
composable(Screen.LoginScreen.route) {
                LoginScreen {
                    Log.d("AppMainNavigation", "AppMainNavigation: ${navController.backQueue}")
                    navController.navigate(Screen.HomeBaseScreen.route){
                        popUpTo(Screen.LoginScreen.route){
                            inclusive = true
                        }
                        launchSingleTop = true
                    }
                }
            }
```

GitHub Link :
https://github.com/rramprasad/BloomApp/blob/main/app/src/main/java/dev/ramprasad/bloom/MainActivity.kt

Comment: Link doesn’t work.

Comment: Try `popUpTo(0)` Pop up will try to pop all non-matching destinations from the back stack until this destination is found. `0` id must not be in the backstack for this to work

Answer (score 2):

update your jetpack compose version to the latest release preview version and all other dependencies.
current jetpack composes version: `1.0.0-rc02`

and also which screen you want to popup just use this

my splash screen code:

```
 @Composable
 fun Navigate(navController: NavController) {
    produceState(initialValue = -1) {
        delay(1500)
        navController.popBackStack()
        val route = if (Firebase.auth.currentUser == null) AppRouter.Intro.route else AppRouter.Home.route
        navController.navigate(route)
    }
 }
```

so here you can use this below line to remove screen from backstack

```
navController.popBackStack()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is doesn't help.
My case is - I have a drawer with several items. And I want each item to clear the backstack. So when user clicks back on that screen - he finishes the app. 
As a last resort, I will listen to back click... But ideally, would like to solve this with navigation.

Comment: @rocknow did you figure out?

Comment: @rocknow did you find it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `WelcomeScreen`'s route as a parameter in `popUpTo` function. It clears all backstack's entries before `WelcomeScreen`, and if `inclusive = true` then `WelcomeScreen` too.

```
navController.navigate(Screen.HomeBaseScreen.route) {
    popUpTo(Screen.WelcomeScreen.route) { inclusive = true }
}
```

Also, if you use parameters in the route, you have to use them in `popUpTo` as well.

```
navController.navigate(Screen.HomeBaseScreen.route) {
    popUpTo(Screen.WelcomeScreen.route + "/{someId}") { inclusive = true }
}
```